# libgdx draw issue and animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

it seems as though i cannot get the draw method to work???
it seems as though the bullet.draw(batcher) 
does not work and i cannot understand why as the bullet is a sprite.
i have made a Sprite[] and added them as animation.
could that be it?

i tried

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY(), bullet.getOriginX() / 2, bullet.getOriginY() / 2, bullet.getWidth(), bullet.getHeight(), 1, 1, bullet.getRotation());
```

but that dont work, the only way it draws is this

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY());
```

below is the code.

// this is in a Asset Class

```
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("SpriteN1.png"));
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);

bullet1 = new Sprite(texture, 380, 350, 45, 20);
bullet1.flip(false, true);

bullet2 = new Sprite(texture, 425, 350, 45, 20);
bullet2.flip(false, true);

Sprite[] bullets = { bullet1, bullet2 };
bulletAnimation = new Animation(0.06f, bullets);
bulletAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

// this is the GameRender class

```
public class GameRender() {
private Bullet bullet;
private Ball ball;

public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
myWorld = world;
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
cam.setToOrtho(true, 480, 320);

batcher = new SpriteBatch();
// Attach batcher to camera
batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

// Call helper methods to initialize instance variables
initGameObjects();
initAssets();
}

private void initGameObjects() {
ball = GameWorld.getBall();
bullet = myWorld.getBullet();
scroller = myWorld.getScroller();
}

private void initAssets() {
ballAnimation = AssetLoader.ballAnimation;
bulletAnimation = AssetLoader.bulletAnimation;
}

public void render(float runTime) {

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batcher.begin();
// Disable transparency 
// This is good for performance when drawing images that do not require
// transparency.
batcher.disableBlending();

// The ball needs transparency, so we enable that again.
batcher.enableBlending();


batcher.draw(AssetLoader.ballAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),         ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());

batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(),     bullet.getY());

// End SpriteBatch
batcher.end();
}
}
```

// this is the gameworld class

```
public class GameWorld {

public static Ball ball;
private Bullet bullet;
private ScrollHandler scroller;

public GameWorld() {
ball = new Ball(480, 273, 32, 32);
bullet = new Bullet(10, 10);
scroller = new ScrollHandler(0);
}

public void update(float delta) {
ball.update(delta);
bullet.update(delta);
scroller.update(delta);
}

public static Ball getBall() {
return ball;
}

public ScrollHandler getScroller() {
return scroller;
}

public Bullet getBullet() { 
return bullet;
}
}
```

is there anyway so make the sprite work?

Comment: anybody? i'll take any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialise the bullet first, then it should work. If not then do this:

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
             bullet.getX(),
             bullet.getY(),
             bullet.getOriginX(),
             bullet.getOriginY(),
             bullet.getWidth(),
             bullet.getHeight(),
             1,
             1,
             bullet.getRotation());
```